# Ethereum Error: authentication needed: password or unlock

Tags: node.js, azure, blockchain, ethereum, geth

`0|server   | (node:99208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 53): Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`

This is happening randomly, sometimes the api call pass through successfully, and sometimes nodejs app logs show this. I unlocked the account multiple times using multiple ways giving me "true" boulean as follows:

`personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, "cDxxxxxxxxKaYZ", 300)`

`geth --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'cDb
xxxxxxxKaYZ', 1000)" attach`

it keep on randomly showing the same error authentican needed with no clue!

P.S. I am using azure ethereum consortium network with Geth and MetaMask

Comment: "This is happening randomly"...Is it correlated with the duration you're specifying?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.. It was an issue in the load balancing server as my architecture is composed of multiple servers.. thats why some requests were successful and otheres were not!

Comment: Hi Zein,
We are also using same azure setup for ethereum. The above issue is very random for us too. Could you please tell me how you resolved from network side.
Thanks.